# Best practice for logging out of React Native app?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-context

I have currently implemented the sign out functionality on my app with (using firebase authentication):

```
const handleSignOut = () => {
  signOut(auth)
    .then(() => navigation.navigate("Login"))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};
```

However, I understand this isn't enough as I notice that some state is being preserved accross users (state is preserved even after logout), and I was wondering what the best way to clear/reset all the state is.

Do I need to manually unmount all my components (I still don't quite understand how/when component unmounting happens), or is there an easy way I can achieve this using navigation or context tools?

I am using the Context API and React Navigation:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        headerMode="none"
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Register"
          component={RegisterScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say because a lot of this is application specific, but generally speaking, you need to dedicate a single method which is capable destroying a user's session, and making sure that's persistent. Maybe it's logging out of Firebase, maybe it's clearing some cookies, maybe it's updating some other persistent state.

The point is, you write a single method which is responsible for performing all of the data actions to make sure that session doesn't exist any more. Importantly, it's not associated with any navigation or whatever. It's just the pure data operations.

Then you have this reusable function to log the user out that can be called from wherever. Applied to your example...

```js
// Notice that things that can possibly fail are wrapped in dedicated try/catches.
// You don't want the failure to clear some state prevent your ability to clear others.
const doSomeBigGlobalSessionLogout = async () => {
  const maybeErrors = [];
  try {
    await firebase.signOut(auth);
  } catch (e) {
    maybeErrors.push(e);
  }
  try {
    await clearSomeOtherPersistentState();
  } catch (e) {
    maybeErrors.push(e);
  }

  /* do something with errors */
  // for (error of maybeErrors) { ... }

  // Still resolve successfully, because you won't want to lock the user from
  // not being able to sign out.
  return Promise.resolve();
};

// Here you can trust it will never lock the user out, and will always clear state as best as it can.
doSomeBigGlobalSessionLogout()
   // You *will* get here.
  .then(() => navigation.navigate("Login"));
```

Finally in terms of the UI, it would probably make sense to move the user first. Otherwise the user would see their state disappear from the screen before their eyes!

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => navigation.navigate("SomePlaceThatsPretty"));
  .then(doSomeBigGlobalSessionLogout)
  .then(() => navigation.navigate("Login"));
```

Comment: When I clear some persistent state, do I need to literally go into every page/screen I have and set all state variables to their default values? Because this seems very cumbersome, and I would need to change it every time I add another state variable to the project.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do so, provided that these components which may hang onto any dynamically-assigned data related to an authenticated user are unmounted. In the example, you use `navigation.navigate("Login")` to clear the state, but I'd recommend using `navigation.reset` to ensure any previously active screens have been unmounted.

Comment: So which persistent state would I manually need to clear? Would I just need to clear the state in the Context API?